# Problems with simultaneous ODBC connection to web server hosting pages

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc

I have an issue with a SQL Server Express install. I have a test server set up called ASPDEMO running server03, IIS6, SSEE08R2. MgmtStudio installed.

When I access the web site from a computer on the LAN all is well, I can login to the site and hit the db with no problem.

If I try to set up an ODBC connection to ASPDEMO I can connect and link to tables from Access for example, no problem.

But I can't do both at the same time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In Management Studio, connect to the database and right-click on the instance. Choose Properties. When the Server Properties window pops up, Click Connections in the list on the left and check the maximum number of connections allowed. Maybe it is set to 1.

Comment: Number of Users is set to 5 (I think its the default.)   I also clicked on View Connection Properties, but could not find any reference to any having to do with # of connections. But I may have been looking at the master DB, could find a way to check my web DB, even by right clicking on it still brought up Master.

Comment: Set it to zero, if Express will allow this.

Comment: I ahve it set to zero, its was there by default, but I still can not have simultaneous ODBC connections when users are on the site.